# How to add border to the excel file data using aggrid export as csv feature?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, ag-grid

Using aggrid free version, I'm able to export data in the grid as csv.
But I wish to add border to the data only when download csv file (not in the grid view). Is this possible in the free version? If so, how?

```
var excelParams = {
            onlySelected: rowsToExport(),
            columnKeys: ['A', 'B'],
            processCellCallback: formattingFunction,
            fileName: "Report.csv",
        };
gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(excelParams);
```

Note: `rowsToExport()` and `formattingFunction` are my custom functions and the above code works and downloads the data in csv

Answer (score 0):

CSV can't contain style information. You should be able to get this to work when using the Excel export (enterprise version).

As an alternative you might want to consider adding xlsx to your project. It allows you to read the CSV and turn it into an XLS file. See https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-excel/ for a direction on how to do so.